# Paypal IPN sends back VERIFIED but with numbers before and after

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

Paypal [documentation says](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#protocol_and_arch):

> PayPal sends a single word back, which is either VERIFIED if the
>   message originated with PayPal or INVALID if there is any discrepancy
>   with what was originally sent

However, I get the following IPN notification from Paypal (NOTE:I'm using Sandbox for testing):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
.... [removed headers for brevity]
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

8
VERIFIED
0
```

What are the numbers 8 and 0 before and after VERIFIED? My guess 8 is length of the VERIFIED word but that's just a guess.

**update** As PayPal_Robert correctly pointed out, this is because of HTTP chunked transfer encoding. From [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding):

> The size of each chunk is sent right before the chunk itself so that
>   the receiver can tell when it has finished receiving data for that
>   chunk. The data transfer is terminated by a final chunk of length
>   zero.

Comment: deliberately sending back wrong data to get `INVALID` gives back the number 7 so it looks like your length guess may be correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of [chunked HTTP data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) and a regular `fsockopen()` integration including this in the response.

You can either apply `trim()` to trim this and look at INVALID/VERIFIED specifically, or switch from `fsockopen()` to cURL (assuming you're using PHP).

Personally, I would advise you to use a proper HTTP library like cURL as opposed to fsockopen(), as it allows for greater flexibility, both now and in the future.