# Php IPN VERIFIED and strcmp doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a strange problem with VERIFIED string received by PayPal in IPN system.
I use php to check the validity of the payment.
Up to yesterday at 5 pm all worked fine.
But with the last 2 payments, my script can not rescue the "VERIFIED" string anymore.
Here you are my script:

```
[...]
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
[...]
if (!$fp)
  {[...]
  }
else
  {fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
   while (!feof($fp))
     {$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
      $ResTotale .= $res;
      if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
        {// Payment ok!
         [...]
        }
   [...]
  }
```

It worked till yesterday, when we received those data from PayPal:

```
[...]
domain=.paypal.com VERIFIED
[...]
```

With last two payment, we received this:

```
[...]
8
VERIFIED
0
[...]
```

And the script mark this payment as INVALID.
I changed the "strcmp" if statement with this:

```
if ((strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) || (strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED") == 0) || (trim($res) == "VERIFIED"))
```

Can anyone tell me if this script will work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. In the WeekEnd we received a payment and it was successfully elaborated. PayPal reply to us without "8" and "0" around "VERIFIED". So I don't know if the simple "strcmp" would work the same. Anyway, the problem is resolved on our side. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check [Paypal IPN sends back VERIFIED but with numbers before and after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218657/paypal-ipn-sends-back-verified-but-with-numbers-before-and-after)

Furthermore, the evaluation should work by including trim()

if (strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED") == 0)

See: https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/926/kw/http%201.1

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found a really easy work around I changed the function :

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
```

By

```
if (strpos($res,'VERIFIED') !== false) {
```

So anywhere you used strcmp must be changed to strpos.

I hope this will help some of you :)

Mouns

Comment: Thank you dear you avoid me psychatric hospital. I love you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I was having the same problem and the only thing that worked for me was to use `if (strpos($res, "VERIFIED") !== 0)`. 
Hope it helps.